Pinescript not working on external broker
My broker uses the tradingview chart, but unfortunately I can't load any of the tradingview custom indicators I have favourited from there, so I thought I'd copy-paste them, but when I do a red exclamation mark appears, saying "Study error - Unknown study name" and they are not displayed.
In the scripts, though, the indicator function is called with a title and a subtitle, so I don't think that is the problem.
This is the script I'm trying to load:
// This Pine Script™ code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © ChartPrime

//@version=5
indicator("LOWESS (Locally Weighted Scatterplot Smoothing) [ChartPrime]", "Lowess & GaussianMA [ChartPrime]",
         overlay            = true,
         max_lines_count    = 500,
         max_labels_count   = 500)


// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//   
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------{

// @variable Length for LOWESS calculation
int length      = input.int(30, minval=1, title="Length", group = "LOWESS (Locally Weighted Scatterplot Smoothing)")

// @variable Number of bars to the left for pivot calculation
int leftBars    = input.int(5, "Length", group = "Pivots")
// @variable Number of bars to the right for pivot calculation
int rightBars   = leftBars - 2
// @variable Toggle to show break count
bool show_count = input.bool(false, "Count Breaks", group = "===")
// @variable Toggle to show Gaussian scatterplot
bool Gaussian_plot = input.bool(false, "Gaussian Scatterplot")

// @variable Line object for high pivot
var line line_h = na
// @variable Line object for low pivot
var line line_l = na

// @variable Label object for high pivot
var label lbl_h = na
// @variable Label object for low pivot
var label lbl_l = na

// @variable Counter for upward breaks
var count_up    = 0
// @variable Counter for downward breaks
var count_dn    = 0

// @variable Color for upward movements
color col_up = #60befd
// @variable Color for downward movements
color col_dn = #ab61ff


// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//  
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------{

// Calculate pivot high and low
ph = ta.pivothigh(leftBars, rightBars)
pl = ta.pivotlow(leftBars, rightBars)

//@function Calculates LOWESS (Locally Weighted Scatterplot Smoothing)
//@param src (float) Source series
//@param length (int) Lookback period
//@returns (float) LOWESS value
lowess(src, length) =>
    sum_w = 0.0
    sum_wx = 0.0
    sum_wy = 0.0
    for i = 0 to length - 1
        w = math.pow(1 - math.pow(i / length, 3), 3)
        sum_w += w
        sum_wx += w * i
        sum_wy += w * src[i]
    a = sum_wy / sum_w
    b = sum_wx / sum_w
    a + b / (length - 1) / 2000

//@function Calculates Modified Adaptive Gaussian Moving Average
//@param src (float) Source series
//@param length (int) Lookback period
//@returns [float, float] Gaussian MA and smoothed Gaussian MA
GaussianMA(src, length)=>
    h_l                = array.new<float>(length)

    float gma          = 0.0
    float sumOfWeights = 0.0
    float sigma        = (ta.atr(length) + ta.stdev(close, length)) / 2  // Volatility adaption
    float highest      = 0.0
    float lowest       = 0.0
    float smoothed     = 0.0

    for i = 0 to length - 1
        h_l.push(close[i])
        highest      := h_l.max()
        lowest       := h_l.min()
        weight        = math.exp(-math.pow(((i - (length - 1)) / (2 * sigma)), 2) / 2)
        value         = math.max(highest[i], highest) + math.min(lowest[i], lowest)
        gma          := gma + (value * weight)
        sumOfWeights += weight

    gma := (gma / sumOfWeights) / 2

    smoothed := lowess(gma, 10)

    [gma, smoothed]

[gma, smoothed] = GaussianMA(close, length)

// Generate random color for Gaussian MA plot
random1       = math.random(0, 255)
gmaColor      = color.rgb(random1, random1, random1)

// Determine color for smoothed line based on its direction
smoothedColor =    smoothed > smoothed[2]  ? col_up 
                 : smoothed <= smoothed[2]  ? col_dn 
                 : na


// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
// 
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------{

plot(gma, "Gaussian Moving Average", bar_index % 4 == 0 ? (Gaussian_plot ? gmaColor : na) : na, 1, plot.style_cross)

plot(smoothed, "Gaussian Moving Average", smoothedColor)
plot(smoothed, "Gaussian Moving Average", color.new(smoothedColor, 80), 5)

// Draw lines and labels for pivot highs
if smoothedColor == col_up and ph
    line_h := line.new(bar_index[rightBars], high[rightBars], bar_index[rightBars], high[rightBars])
    lbl_h  := label.new(na, high[rightBars], "⬥",color = #00000000, textcolor = col_up, size = size.large)

// Handle crossovers for pivot highs
if ta.crossover(close, line_h.get_y1())
    count_dn := 0
    count_up += 1
    line_h.set_x2(bar_index),  line_h.set_color(color.new(col_up, 30))
    lbl_h.set_x(bar_index)

    if not show_count
        lbl_h.set_style(label.style_label_center)
    if show_count
        lbl_h.set_y(high)
        lbl_h.set_size(size.normal)    
        lbl_h.set_style(label.style_label_down)
        lbl_h.set_text(str.tostring(count_up))

    line_h := na    

// Draw lines and labels for pivot lows
if smoothedColor == col_dn and pl
    line_l := line.new(bar_index[rightBars], low[rightBars], bar_index[rightBars], low[rightBars])
    lbl_l  := label.new(na, low[rightBars], "⬥", color = #00000000, textcolor = col_dn, size = size.large)

// Handle crossunders for pivot lows
if ta.crossunder(close, line_l.get_y1())
    count_up := 0
    count_dn += 1
    line_l.set_x2(bar_index),  line_l.set_color(color.new(col_dn, 30))
    lbl_l.set_x(bar_index)

    if not show_count
        lbl_l.set_style(label.style_label_center)
    if show_count
        lbl_l.set_y(low)
        lbl_l.set_size(size.normal)  
        lbl_l.set_style(label.style_label_up)
        lbl_l.set_text(str.tostring(count_dn))

    line_l := na

// Trend Change Points
plotshape(smoothed, "",
 shape.diamond, 
 location.absolute, 
 color  = ta.crossover(smoothed, smoothed[2]) ? col_up : ta.crossunder(smoothed, smoothed[2]) ? col_dn : na, 
 offset = 0, 
 size   = size.tiny
 )

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}

I have tried copy-pasting different scripts, contacting tradingview support (they have not replied) and changing the script's version, but nothing seems to work.

No broker allows custom Pinescript indicators.
From Tradingview you must send alerts via webhook to your broker.
